# Find weights using Gauss-Lobatto-Legendre scheme with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

I am interested in finding quadrature weights of the 2D polynomial expansion over x and y interval [-1,1] using 6 points using the Gauss-Legendre integration scheme. I want to use numpy.polynomial.legendre.legval2d (polynomial.legendre.legval2d(x, y, c)) to do this, but am unsure about what values I should be inputting in the C matrix.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import legendre

coefs = np.zeros((6, 6))
coefs[-1][-1] = 1
c = np.append(np.zeros(5), 1)
x_ = np.append(np.append(-1, legendre.Legendre(c).deriv().roots()), 1)
y_ = np.append(np.append(-1, legendre.Legendre(c).deriv().roots()), 1)


Ln = legendre.legval2d(x_, y_, coefs)
```

This final line should be giving me both negative and positive weights from [-1,1], but is giving me the following

```
[1.         0.10309967 0.00977511 0.00977511 0.10309967 1.        ]
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.